# How to format tabular data in a python or operating system popup dialog

Tags: python, user-interface, zenity

I'm using zenity, a dialog/GUI popup tool, from within python in order to display some tabular data. I'd like to do something like the following:

```
 zenity --title "werwrwqer" --info --html --text="  <table><tr><td>A</td><td> 14 </td></tr>  <tr><td> B </td><td> 15 </td></tr>  </table>  <table><tr><td>A</td><td> 14 </td></tr>  <tr><td> C </td><td> 16 </td></tr> <tr><td>D</td><td>1</td></tr> </table>"
```

But that fails. Is there any easy way to display a series of tables in a popup text display?

Edit: In fact, the example in the Gnome documentation is precisely a list without any checkboxes or radio buttons:

```
zenity --list \
   --title="Choose the Bugs You Wish to View" \
   --column="Bug Number" --column="Severity" --column="Description" \
     992383 Normal "GtkTreeView crashes on multiple selections" \
     293823 High "GNOME Dictionary does not handle proxy" \
     393823 Critical "Menu editing does not work in GNOME 2.0"
```

However, it is a selection tool, allowing the user to choose one row.  My original question asked how to display a *series* of tables, since I don't just want to show one tabular set. And I'd rather not have any interactivity.
Something like HTML formatting would be needed, then?
My current solution (awful), btw, is to generate and compile some LaTeX and pop up a PDF viewer.
Colors would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

Zenity supports a list construct (with columns and selectors - radio buttons and multi selections).  I have written a wrapper class around the Zenity tool, but I am on my phone so I am unable to share with you.  There are simar classes by others - search for pyZenity for one such example.

Comment: Hi Tony. I do not see how that is relevant to my question. I want to format the layout of text, not to offer selectors.

Comment: With a list you can format text into a table (your example is trying to build a table), but the selectors are optional if you don't need them.

Comment: Ahhh. I've clarified my question, then. It did, originally, say " Is there any easy way to display a series of tables in a popup text display?" but maybe I should change the question title now.

Comment: in which case - there is no way in Zenity to show complex data structures - i.e. multiple tables and colours. Zenity is intended for simple GUIs on scripts.

Comment: @ToySuffolk66 -- Thank you. Very well. Of course, my question is not about Zenity, either -- that was just my starting point. Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion (for what it is worth) would be to use the webbrowser module to display your formatted data.